# What broke Firefox? After upgrade to 14.04 Firefox plugin-container eats 179% CPU

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, firefox, performance

After my recent upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 Firefox plugin-container eats 179% CPU, even after disabling all plugins and restarting the browser. Before the upgrade I did not have this problem, though Firefox performance was poor. Is this a known issue, or have I encountered something new? Am I the only one having this?

Had to shift over to Chromium as Firefox had become unresponsive, eating all of CPU and thus completely unusable.

I tested it last night with `firefox -safe-mode` and the result was that my whole system become unresponsive for about 10 minutes, before I was able to log in via virtual console and kill the firefox process.

Comment: Firefox plugin-container is the process where Firefox runs its plugins. Your problem is not with firefox itself but with some plugin. Flash is the usual suspect here.

Comment: Does this happen with just an empty page showing? (and all plugins disabled)

Comment: I tested it last night with `firefox -safe-mode` and the result was that my whole system become unresponsive for about 10 minutes, before I was able to log in via virtual console and kill the firefox process. (updated my question with this info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solution.

Open firefox and type into url - "about:config" (without "") and press enter.

After what, on the page that appears with the warning, click the "I promise I'll be careful!" (or another "promise" :)).

On opened page with mozilla settings looked for a "dom.ipc.plugins.enabled" (without "") (use the filter on top).

All founded options set to "false" (just double click on each option).

Then restart firefox.

Comment: What does this exactly do? Can you please elaborate?